# Document read count if does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am reading a document simply in Firestore from my Ionic5 app.

```
let data = await this.afs.doc('user/1234').ref.get();
if(data.exists){ return data.data(); }
```

1. If the data does not exist, will it still be counted as one read?
2. If the data exists, I am using both `exists` and `.data()`. So will the above code be counted as one read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each API call will count as at least one read operation, so this will indeed lead to a single document read charge.
2. Since you're only getting the document once, this will indeed lead to a single document read operation. Accessing the same document snapshot repeatedly does not lead to additional charges.

Comment: Thx for the clarification.